# SQL Vlookup on multiple columns with single column of another table

Tags: sql-server

**Table A**
Employee_ID(Type A) 
Employee_Name
Employee_ID(Type B)
Employee Name

**Table B**
Employee_ID(Any Type)
Employee_MGR

I need **Table C** as below via a query (no tables,no view creation needed)

Employee_ID(Type A) 
Employee_Name
Employee_MGR
Employee_ID(Type B)
Employee Name
Employee_MGR

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference, your questions will get more attention if you spend more time making them easier for people to understand and answer. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. [SO - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) In fact, if you edit this question, it will push it back up the queue and you may get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join to the manager table twice, once for each employee ID type.

I would be remiss if I didn't point out that this is a terrible data model, but I'm sure you already know that.

Setting up the tables:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE
  (
    [Employee_ID(Type A)] INT
   ,[Employee_Name]       VARCHAR(20)
   ,[Employee_ID(Type B)] INT
   ,[Employee Name]       VARCHAR(20)
  );

INSERT
  @TableA
  (
    [Employee_ID(Type A)]
   ,Employee_Name
   ,[Employee_ID(Type B)]
   ,[Employee Name]
  )
VALUES
  (1,'Bob',2,'Robert')
 ,(3,'Sue',4,'Susan');

DECLARE @TableB TABLE
  (
    [Employee_ID(Any Type)] INT
   ,[Employee_MGR]          VARCHAR(20)
  );

INSERT
  @TableB
  (
    [Employee_ID(Any Type)]
   ,Employee_MGR
  )
VALUES
  (1,'Mary')
 ,(2,'Helen')
 ,(3,'Joe')
 ,(4,'Harry');

DECLARE @tableC TABLE
  (
    [Employee_ID(Type A)]  INT
   ,[Employee_Name]        VARCHAR(20)
   ,[Employee_MGR(Type A)] VARCHAR(20)
   ,[Employee_ID(Type B)]  INT
   ,[Employee Name]        VARCHAR(20)
   ,[Employee_MGR(Type B)] VARCHAR(20)
  );
```

Here's your end query:

```
INSERT
  @tableC
  (
    [Employee_ID(Type A)]
   ,Employee_Name
   ,[Employee_MGR(Type A)]
   ,[Employee_ID(Type B)]
   ,[Employee Name]
   ,[Employee_MGR(Type B)]
  )
SELECT
  emp.[Employee_ID(Type A)]
 ,emp.Employee_Name
 ,mgrA.Employee_MGR
 ,emp.[Employee_ID(Type B)]
 ,emp.[Employee Name]
 ,mgrB.Employee_MGR
FROM
  @TableA AS emp
  JOIN
    @TableB AS mgrA
      ON
      mgrA.[Employee_ID(Any Type)] = emp.[Employee_ID(Type A)]
  JOIN
    @TableB AS mgrB
      ON
      mgrB.[Employee_ID(Any Type)] = emp.[Employee_ID(Type B)];
```

And this is what it gives you:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  @tableC;

+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+
| Employee_ID(Type A) | Employee_Name | Employee_MGR(Type A) | Employee_ID(Type B) | Employee Name | Employee_MGR(Type B) |
+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+
|                   1 | Bob           | Mary                 |                   2 | Robert        | Helen                |
|                   3 | Sue           | Joe                  |                   4 | Susan         | Harry                |
+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works for me.  Regarding data model , its just small part of a multi-dimensional one, hence  may look garbage to us :)